# Escape string from EditText

Tags: android, http, get, escaping, android-edittext

I was just wondering, if I have an EditText that I'm turning the content of into a string, say

```
String queryStr = new String(searchText.getText().toString());
```

How would I go about escaping special characters from this string so that I could put it into an HttpGet method? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [java.net.URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

```
java.net.URLEncoder.encode(queryStr, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
TextUtils.htmlEncode(queryStr);
```

I think that should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try smth like this:

```
import android.net.Uri;

...

private String getParams(String queryStr) {
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.appendQueryParameter("your_parameter_key", queryStr);
    return builder.toString();
}
```

It will give you the properly encoded params string to append to your base url.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, there's no reason to use new String() here.

```
String queryStr = new String(searchText.getText().toString());
```

should just be

```
String queryStr = searchText.getText().toString();
```